# C# How to delete the first line of my text files?

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader, writer

I want to create a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio that writes text files on a button click.

I have a txt file (e.g. test.txt) which contains

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EOS
FFFF
GGGG
HHHH
IIII
EOS
JJJJ
KKKK
LLLL
MMMM
NNNN
EOS
EOF
```

Then I would like to split it into number of other txt files

```
**bag1.txt**
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EOS

**bag2.txt**
EEEE
FFFF
GGGG
IIII
EOS

**bag3.txt**
JJJJ
KKKK
LLLL
MMMM
NNNN
EOS
EOF
```

these is the code,

```
private void read3btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = textBox1.Text;
        TextReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
          //This allows you to do one Read operation.

        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();;
        sr.Close();

        string[] bags = s.Split(new string[] {"EOS"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

        // This will give you an array of strings (minus the EOS field)
        // Then write the files...

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Program-program\tesfile\bag1.txt", bags[0] + "EOS");  //< -- Add this you need the EOS at the end field the field

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Program-program\tesfile\bag2.txt", bags[1] + "EOS");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Program-program\tesfile\bag3.txt", bags[2] + "EOS" + bags[3]);

   }}
```

Then the output comes this way

```
**bag1.txt**
    AAAA
    BBBB
    CCCC
    DDDD
    EOS

**bag2.txt**

EEEE
FFFF
GGGG
IIII
EOS

**bag3.txt**

JJJJ
KKKK
LLLL
MMMM
NNNN
EOS
EOF
```

unfortunately the output in bags[1] and bags[2] has a blank line in the first line, is there anyway to update the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `"EOS"` separator does not contain a newline. Try:

```
string[] bags = s.Split(new string[] {"EOS\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Your input file is

```
...DDDD\nEOS\nEEEE\n...
```

After splitting with your code, you get:

```
...DDDD\n  EOS  \nEEEE\n...
```

Notice the leading `\n` before `EEEE`. By including `\n` in your separator, you will get:

```
...DDDD\n  EOS\n  EEEE\n...
```

Comment: Unless the newline is `\r` or `\r\n`

Comment: I suppose it could be. I'll leave that up to the OP to determine for his specific input text file.

Comment: it's bugging, it's said Index was outside the bounds of the array. :(

Comment: ah yes, thankyou very much Greg finally i understand after debugging it :D

Answer (score 1):

Call `.Trim()` to remove the leading whitespace.

Comment: hi slaks where should i put it?

Comment: On the string you want to trim.

Comment: umm yes i've tried it, but then it cuts of the last line at EOS so the output become IIIIEOS without a newline :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's not a big problem :)
When you read your file, you get a string like "AAA\nBBB\nCCC\nDDD\nEOS\nEEE\nFFF\n...EOS\nJJJ\n..."
If tou trim the string only on "EOS", you get this:

"AAA\nBBB\nCCC\nDDD\n" "\nEEE\nFFF\n..." "\nJJJ..."

Because the Split() method removes the "EOS" string, but not the new line it follows :)

```
string[] bags = s.Split(new string[] {"EOS\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

..this should work fine :)